# Upload an asset in a custom form

Tags: entries, assets, form, guest-entries

I am trying to upload/add an asset to an entry via a form on the website. The entry saves fine when I don't include the asset field but as soon as I add the asset field and try to upload a file I get this odd SQL error.

> CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`housewares`.`craft_relations`, CONSTRAINT `craft_relations_targetId_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`targetId`) REFERENCES `craft_elements` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE).
>   The SQL statement executed was: INSERT INTO `craft_relations` (`fieldId`, `sourceId`, `sourceLocale`, `targetId`, `sortOrder`, `dateCreated`, `dateUpdated`, `uid`) VALUES (:row0_col0, :row0_col1, NULL, :row0_col3, :row0_col4, :row0_col5, :row0_col6, :row0_col7). Bound with :row0_col0='4', :row0_col1='27', :row0_col3='Golfclubs.jpg', :row0_col4=1, :row0_col5='2014-09-03 23:36:06', :row0_col6='2014-09-03 23:36:06', :row0_col7='a1e565e1-f6d3-4f3b-8a6f-2c049d236b13'

The field works fine in the CP.

This is the field

```
<input class="form-control" type="file" id="image" name="fields[image][]" />
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Problem solved! (head slap)

The `<form>` requires the following parameters:
`enctype="multipart/form-data"`

An odd error that gets thrown if omitted.

Comment: Same here, <form enctype="multipart/form-data"> fixed the issue.